# JSF with use of BootsFaces. BootsFaces Not working

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I have such code as follow in my input.xhtml file which takes input from user. But this BootsFaces code is not working, Please Someone help me to solve this problem if any one faced it Before.

```
<b:form id="studentForm" styleClass="form-horizontal">
              <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
                <b:inputText label="E-mail:" labelStyle="width:80px;">
                  <f:facet name="prepend">
                    <h:inputText value="#{studentBean.firstName}" styleClass="form-control" />
                  </f:facet>
                </b:inputText>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <b:commandButton value="Create" action="#{studentBean.createStudentForm}" styleClass="btn btn-default" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
</b:form>
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: .. please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Hey @JasperdeVries, I will be Very thankful of yours if you can help me in my problem as I have explained real scenario here in my question, Please suggest me how to overcome this problem.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You are now giving us not much to work with. And please define "not working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `b:inputText` incorrectly. You should not wrap a `h:inputText` in it. You can bind the value using the `b:inputText` tag:

```
<b:inputText label="First name:"
             labelStyle="width:80px;"
             value="#{studentBean.firstName}"/>
```

See also:

- https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/forms/inputText.jsf (documentation).
- https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFacesWeb (if you want to download the showcase and its examples).

Comment: Thank You, I have refer documentations and it was useful for me.  @Jasper de Vries

Comment: @Nishral If this answered your question, please accept it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)